Linker problems trying to compile with the Chipmunk Physics Library
I am on Windows.
I downloaded the latest source from here: https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D and unzipped it.
I opened up the Chipmunk2D-master folder in VSCodium and used the CMake Tools extension to configure and then build the project. It completed successfully.
The Demo program was created and runs fine.
the build/src folder was created containing:
cmake_install.cmake
libchipmunk.a
libchipmunk.dll
libchipmunk.dll.a
Makefile

I copied libchipmunk.dll to my project's folder.
For context on the project, I was previously compiling the library's source directly with my own code. Everything was working fine except for the clunkyness of having chipmunk's 30+ .c files in my makefile. So basically all of this is just an attempt at doing it "correctly" and using the DLL.
I changed all the chipmunk #includes in my code from relative paths to #include <chipmunk.h>, and added to the makefile:
-IC:/path/to/Chipmunk2D-master/include/chipmunk
-LC:/path/to/Chipmunk2D-master/build/src
-lchipmunk

at their appropriate places. Attempting to compile the project with minGW throws dozens of linker errors like undefined reference to `cpBodySetVelocity', one for each chipmunk function called in my code.
here's the compilation command:
gcc my_sources.c 
-IC:/SDL/SDL2-2.26.4/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 
-IC:/path/to/Chipmunk2D-master/include/chipmunk 
-LC:/SDL/SDL2-2.26.4/i686-w64-mingw32/lib 
-LC:/path/to/Chipmunk2D-master/build/src 
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lchipmunk 
-o MyProject

I've inspected the .dll and the names are all in there. I've triple checked spellings, everything. Any insight is appreciated.

"at their appropriate places" or maybe not so appropriate. How should we know? Please show your actual makefile.

I added the compile command.

Have you tried forcing either static or shared build (gcc flag -static/-shared)?
If the default is shared build then cpBodySetVelocity looks to me like a static symbol, so it is probably missing __declspec(dllimport) in its definition. Maybe you could try to add compiler flag -DCP_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport).

reddit user skeeto figured it out for me:
https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/1fagx4c/linker_problems_trying_to_compile_with_the/
I was mixing 32 and 64 bits toolchains. VSCode compiled the chipmunk dll in 64 bits (I wasn't aware of this. That was my problem.), but for my project I was compiling with mingw32-make, and the 32 bit SDL package. I switched to mingw-W64 to compile and swapped in 64 bit SDL, and it all worked fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It looks to me like there is a bug in chipmunk.h, because it doesn't define CP_EXPORT as __declspec(dllexport) when importing the shared library.
I proposed a patch here: https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D/pull/252
